# How to get child model field value from parent model serializer in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to access child model value from parent model serializer.

**Parent Models**

```py
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**Child Models**

```py
class CourseStaff(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name='course_staff_course')
    staff = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name='course_staff_user')
    enable = models.BooleanField()
```

**Serializer Class**

```py
class TeacherCourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Expected Result**

```json
[
{
    id: 1,
    name: "",
    staff_id: 5, #<---- It will come from the child model.
    is_enabled: true #<---- It will come from the child model.
}
]
```

I tried with this

**Serializer**

```py
class TeacherCourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    enable = serializers.CharField(source='course_staff_course.enable')
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = '__all__'
```

But getting error

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `enable` on serializer `TeacherCourseSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Course` instance.
Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'enable'.
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: one course can have multiple course staff. If enable is the property of course then it should be in course model. Enable in CourseStaff would mean , if the staff is enabled or not. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Course to course staff is one to many relationship. The related manager will not return a single object instead multiple objects. Instead you can try different approach if course is going to have only one staff use [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) and continue in same way.

Other way is to create a [nested serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) for staff and the use in the course serializer.

```
class CourseStaffSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CourseStaff
        fields = '__all__'

class TeacherCourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    teachers = CourseStaffSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
       model = Course
       fields = '__all__'
```